# Postgresql BDR problem compiling pluging

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

I'm trying to build deb packages for postgresql BDR plugin, but I'm getting the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -fPIC -pie -DLINUX_OOM_SCORE_ADJ=0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpic -I/usr/include/postgresql -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.4/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/tcl8.6  -c -o pg_resetxlog.o pg_resetxlog.c
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -fPIC -pie -DLINUX_OOM_SCORE_ADJ=0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpic pg_resetxlog.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -L/usr/lib/mit-krb5 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5  -Wl,--as-needed  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpgcommon -lpgport -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpq -lpgcommon -lpgport -lselinux -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -ledit -lrt -lcrypt -ldl -lm  -o bdr_resetxlog
pg_resetxlog.o: In function `memcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:51: undefined reference to `pg_crc32_table'
pg_resetxlog.o: In function `RewriteControlFile':
/var/lib/postgresql/src/bdr-plugin/pg_resetxlog.c:955: undefined reference to `pg_crc32_table'
pg_resetxlog.o: In function `PrintControlValues':
/var/lib/postgresql/src/bdr-plugin/pg_resetxlog.c:749: undefined reference to `pg_crc32_table'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bdr_resetxlog] Error 1
```

To build this deb package I'm using the following commands:

```
cd ~/src/
git clone -b bdr-plugin/next git://git.postgresql.org/git/2ndquadrant_bdr.git bdr-plugin
git clone -b debian/bdr https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/bdr-packaging bdr-packaging
cp -rfv bdr-packaging/debian bdr-plugin/debian
cd bdr-plugin
dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc
```

About the dependencies, all the postgresql-BDR server are installed, and all postgresql looks ok:

```
# dpkg -l | grep postgresq | grep dev
ii  postgresql-bdr-server-dev-9.4       9.4.5-2trusty                    amd64        development files for PostgreSQL-BDR 9.4 server-side programming
ii  postgresql-server-dev-9.1           9.1.21-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64        development files for PostgreSQL 9.1 server-side programming
ii  postgresql-server-dev-9.2           9.2.16-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64        development files for PostgreSQL 9.2 server-side programming
ii  postgresql-server-dev-9.3           9.3.12-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64        development files for PostgreSQL 9.3 server-side programming
ii  postgresql-server-dev-9.5           9.5.2-1.pgdg14.04+1              amd64        development files for PostgreSQL 9.5 server-side programming
ii  postgresql-server-dev-all           173.pgdg14.04+1                  all          extension build tool for multiple PostgreSQL versions
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue is that [Debian/Ubuntu upgraded `postgresql-server-dev-all` to require `postgresql-server-dev-9.5`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/postgresql-server-dev-all) which in turns requires `libpq-dev` 9.5.

There were changes in libpq 9.5 that broke the patched versions of `pg_resetxlog` and `pg_dump` bundled in BDR.

BDR 1.0 adds compatibility changes to address this, but there's no real way around the issue that when Debian or Ubuntu or PGDG update libpq, it can break previously working packages.